# IPC between ported c++ application and binded proxy on android

Tags: android, android-source

I'm looking for a way to get uid for other proxies (bind using NDK) running on Android. Originally we used UDS (Unix domain socket) to extract uid for the Linux platform, but I have no idea about Android, I googled a bit, and it seems that UDS doesn't work anymore for Android. Could anyone please share some ideas?
Thanks.